# Invalid Key Hash Does Not Match Any Stored Key Hashes

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-authentication

*This is not a duplicate, as I have followed the steps outlined in the question suggested, this resulted in clicking the Facebook button and nothing happening*

I am attempting to implement Facebook login into my android app. However, after clicking through on the FacebookLogin button the error displays:

[image]

What am I missing from the configuration so as to make this work?

**Updated:**
*Manifest:*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".Login.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Login.SignupActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Login.ResetPasswordActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reset_password"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>


</application>
```

Comment: Can you add the `Manifest` file?

Comment: @IulianPopescu I updated the question with the manifest